# Relational Algebra Query Troubles

Tags: database, relational-algebra

I have a problem where I have two relations, one containing attributes song_id, song_name, album_id, and the other containing album_id and album_name. I need to find the names of all the albums that do not have songs in the song relation. The problem is I can only use Rename, Projection, Selection, Grouping(with sum,min,max,count), Cartesian Product, and Natural join. I have spent a good amount of time working on this and would appreciate any help that pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ErwinSmout pointed out, difference is a generally easy way to do it.  But since you can't use it, there is a tricky workaround using counts. I'm assuming that every `album_id` present in the songs relation is also present in the `albums` relation.

`PROJECT` album_id from the songs relation (note that relational algebra's `PROJECT` is equivalent to SQL's `SELECT DISTINCT`). I'll call this relation `song_albums`. Now lets take the count of the `albums` relation, call this m, and take the count of the new table, call this n.

Take the Cartesian product of the albums relation and the song_albums relation. This new relation has m*n rows. Now if you do a count, grouped by `album_name`, each of the m `album_name`'s will have a count of n. Not very helpful.

But now, we `SELECT` from the relation rows where `albums.album_id != song_albums.album_id`. Now, if you do a count grouped by `album_name`, the count for those albums that were not in the original `songs` relation will be n, while those that were originally in there will have a count less than n, since rows would have been removed based on how many songs with that album were in the original `songs` relation.

---

**Edit:** As it turns out, this isn't a *strictly* relational-algebra solution: In SQL, a 1 x 1 table, such as the one containing `n` can simply be treated as an integer and used in an equality comparison. However, according to Wikipedia, [selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_%28relational_algebra%29) must make a comparison between either two attributes of a relation, or an attribute and a *constant* value.

Another obstacle which will be dealt with by another ill-recommended Cartesian product: we can take the Cartesian product of the 1 x 1 relation containing `n` with our most recent relation. Now we can make a proper relational-algebra selection since we have an attribute that is always equal to `n`.

Since this has gotten rather complex, here is a relational-algebra expression capturing the above english explanation:

[image: relational algebra 1]

[image: relational algebra 2]

[image: relational algebra 3]

[image: relational algebra 4]

Note that n is a 1 x 1 relation with an attribute named "count".

Comment: Wow.  If ever there is some "most contorted SQL solution" contest, you should definitely join.  Meanwhile I'll retract my "impossible" and maintain that teachers who teach their students this kind of stuff, should be hung from the highest tree, or at least be kept away from database teaching for all the rest of their lives.

Comment: How would I go about doing the last part in relational algebra since n is an arbitrary number?

Comment: @CodeEnthusiast With more Cartesian product acrobatery! Nice catch, I've edited the solution to accomodate for this. I hope this is a purely academic exercise.

Comment: @DPenner Yeah it is. I also had to implement most of the operators I'm using in Python. I also have to use the grouping operator to find n.

Comment: If you have k distinct albums in total, in the SONGS table, then the GROUP BY (on the restrict on the cartesian product) will show an albums count value of k-1 for albums with matching songs, and an albums count value of k for albums without matching songs.  You can then select only those rows where album_count = SELECT MAX(album_count) from <repeat same restrict/crossjoin here>.  No ?

Comment: max(album_count) would work too, but there's still the problem that a strict relational algebra selection only seems to allow a comparison between two attributes or an attribute and a constant.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible.  The problem includes a negation, and in relational algebra, that can only be epxressed using relational difference, which you're seemingly not allowed to use.

I'm curious to see what your teacher presents as the solution to this problem.

Comment: It turns out to not really be "impossible".  See DPenner's solution.